How does "attempting to influence a public servant by means of deceit" affect political activity?
I just looked up what "attempting to influence a public servant" meant, and found various state code with phrases like

[a]ny person who attempts to influence any public servant by means of deceit with the intent thereby to alter or affect the public servant’s decision, vote, opinion, or action concerning any matter which is to be considered or performed by him.

This sounds remarkably far-reaching.
Is this something that could be charged against anyone writing a letter to a Congressman, speaking at a town hall meeting, or even speaking at a town square urging political action by others, provided the court decides some aspect of the information communicated was false?  If not, what is the delineation?
Note: although this question was prompted by coverage of the case of Tina Peters, but her specific situation isn't really relevant to this question.

It should be clear that in the case of Tina Peters the attempts to influence was related to the various crimes of election interference that she was charged with and not at all related to something like speaking at a town hall meeting or writing a member of congress.

Joe: I don't know that much about the Peters case (and in particular, I don't know in what way she committed those counts according to the court), and I should repeat, my question isn't about that.  Let's try to keep this non-partisan, since my interest actually is about the freedom of expression issues.

The very first paragraph of the article you linked says that she was convicted of charges related to a security breach around a conspiracy theory of a stolen election. If you read that further it should be clear that it wasn't anything close to speaking at a town hall or writing a letter.

This may be better served on Law.SE if you're looking for a more general explanation of the law and its purpose.

Maybe it would be good to study some court cases that were based on this law and showed successful that a public servant was influenced. Again more for law.se.

You seem to be focused on the first part, but you can't really parse laws that way, the crucial part you seem to be ignoring is: "with the intent thereby to alter or affect the public servant’s decision, vote, opinion, or action" In other words, you can't trick an official into doing the wrong thing. Don't you think it would be a problem if someone tricked a police officer into shooting you dead when you did nothing wrong? It's not the lying so much as the intent to affect meaningful actions through lying.

The dictionary of law.com defines:

deceit
n. dishonesty, fraudulent conduct, false statements made knowing them to be untrue, by which the liar intends to deceive a party receiving the statements and expects the party to believe and rely on them.

That is, merely making false statements to a public official is not deceit. Only when the speaker knows the statements to be false, and makes them anyway in an effort to deceive, would he commit a crime.
Being wrong is not a crime. But lying is (when talking to a public official with the intent to influence them).

I've thought of this, but... well, in partisan politics - which is virtually all politics today - there is a very, very, very thin distinction between "lying" and "accepting the facts, rumors, and positions of your faction with a deliberate and consistent lack of critical thinking."  I'm not sure there is even philosophically a distinction between the two, and they are both motivated by social or financial gain.

I am not arguing the law has no loopholes, I am arguing that the law is not overly broad. The prosecution must prove intent to obtain a conviction. If it can not prove intent (i.e. that the statements were knowingly false and made to influence a public official), there won't be a conviction.

@MikeSerfas As an example, Trump/Vance were lying when they said "They're eating the dogs!" (Vance admitted in an interview that they knew it was false and it was just a strategy to get attention to the immigration problem). Their followers who believe them and repeat it are mostly not.

@MikeSerfas in partisan politics ... there is a very, very, very thin distinction.  True, but that ought to be less the case when examined in a court of law.  But, yes, maybe more for SE.Law.

As several courts have held, if the only justification for punishing the speech is that it was a deceitful attempt to influence a public official (and not, for example, a threatening one), then the deceit must rise to a sufficient level to render the speech unprotected by the First Amendment's free speech or right to petition clauses. It can't just be a political lie and must, for example, be actual fraud. See, for example, People v. Janousek.

@DavidSchwartz - I looked at People v. Janousek, and while it is clearly relevant, I only saw reference to the aspect of threats or reprisals.  I doubt deceit is so readily defined.  (They do say to use a dictionary...) Regarding other conversations here, it might be easier for people to evaluate this one in a nonpartisan way by imagining how practical projects with disputed aspects (like windmills or nuclear power plants) would be discussed.

My sense is that the intent of this law is to deter/punish con-jobs directed at public officials: i.e., using subterfuge to convince a public office to take acts outside their purview and against the interests of the general public. This is distinct from bribery or collusion because the targeted public official is convinced that:

Some false or imaginary state of affairs is actually true, and…
Redressing that false or imagined state of affairs is urgent and necessary for public welfare.

In the Tina Peters case, at least one of the following events must have occurred behind closed doors:

Someone convinced Ms. Peters that the election fraud lies were true, and needed immediate and direct intervention
Ms. Peters, knowing the election fraud lies were false, convinced one or more other public officials that the lies were true, and that they needed to give her access to machines and data she had no business interfering with.

Both of these would constitute influencing a public official by deceit.
'Attempting to to influence any public servant by means of deceit' covers the gray area between outright corruption (bribery and influence peddling) and honest execution of public duties. It holds that a public official can be upright and honest, but so disoriented by lies and misinformation provided by malicious actors that s'he ends up committing improprieties and crimes. The laws try to get at and punish the malicious actors behind the lies.

Has anyone been charged with "influencing a public servant" in the Peters case though, as opposed to 'traditional' conspiracy etc.?

@IVFcomesfromthetip: not that I'm aware of, and it would be kind of a difficult case to prove (in the realm of spycraft). The question in the Peters case (and all MAGA cases) is whether Peters earnestly and fervently believes the nonsense she spews, or whether she is cynically lying to advance an unsavory agenda. That's something the courts have to decide, and in this case the court came down heavily on the latter.

@IVFcomesfromthetip Yes, Peters herself (found guilty of three counts of that offence, as well as other offences), Belinda Knisley (charged with the offence but took a plea deal without that offence), Sandra Brown (charged with that offence and pleaded guilty).

Actually, nobody was convicted [in this case] for saying stuff about who won the election or even that the machines were vulnerable (and needed 'immediate' audit). A jury might have given the benefit of the doubt that those were sincerely held beliefs, so deceit would not apply. The deceit counts AFAICT were about topics like misrepresenting whether someone was a state employee. Which even a half-MAGA jury probably would deem a "non-political" matter of fact, rather than "alternative facts".

I'm not convinced the 1st case you linked (which someone else then deleted in rev 3 of the Q) to is incredibly relevant to political activities (unlike the 2nd). Lying is not always protected by the 1st amendment; for example lying under oath. Or breaking parole terms that way, be it with the help of an intermediary. Perhaps more often involved in some political scandals has been lying to the FBI, also not protected. Relatedly, I read that in some states/counties, lying to the police is prosecutable as "Attempt to Influence a Public Servant" in addition to "False Reporting".
Wikipedia has  a longer list of activities/circumstances not covered by (i.e. deemed exceptions to) the 1st amendment, under US state laws.

I'm not inclined to read all the details about the 2nd case but even if
"providing unauthorized access" involved [that election official] merely telling someone a password, that also isn't universally covered by the 1st amendment, see e.g. all the (federal) laws punishing the disclosure of classified materials by most officials. (Some officials have tried unsuccessfully to plead disclosure in the public interest, see e.g. the examples from p. 16 in this CRS report
some of which have Wikipedia pages.)
It is rather more difficult to achieve some balancing [or interests/rights] for the latter kind of issues. There are [case law and constitutional] limitations on whom can be punished for such disclosures, and whistleblower mechanisms for complaining without publicly disclosing the materials as such. Yeah, this is somewhat relevant, because the official in the election case also tried to argue public interest. The concrete mechanisms for [law abiding] whistleblowing etc. would be different in that case, but the general idea is the same.

Some other cases in which someone (in Colorado) was convicted of "attempting to influence a public servant" were a prosecutor who deceived his colleagues to obtain info on a case concerning himself, or a psychologist who allegedly deceived the state for years on her (PhD) degree, and so managed "to serve as a child and family investigator and parental evaluator in child custody cases".
Thus far, I could not find any case where merely making public speeches (even by lying about something), as opposed to direct communication with officials resulted in such charges. Perhaps proving (in court) that a public speech was intended to influence specific officials is rather difficult. So that appears to serve as a de facto delineation barrier of the kind you ask about.
As you yourself kindly pointed out to me, in the Peters case, she was charged with trying to influence specific (named) officials. Again, I'm not inclined to read the whole indictment, but around pp. 10-12 it's clear that emails and conversations were involved, e.g. Peters was accused of convincing one of the three named officials to issue credentials for a certain Mr. Wood, claiming that he was a state employee, but apparently he wasn't. So, this case wasn't about Peters making speeches while running for office.
Some US states did in fact try to go further an prohibit lying by election candidates in a broad manner, but usually these laws were struck down as unconstitutional, see e.g. the 2004 amendment to the Minnesota Fair Campaign Practices Act, struck down by the 8th Circuit (unanimously in 281 Care Comm. v. Arneson, 638 F.3d 621, 625 (8th Cir. 2011)). Roughly: the 8th Circuit decided to enhance the SCOTUS Alvarez standard from intermediate scrutiny to strict scrutiny in the case of political speech. And so they found that the state's argument of "common sense" that lying should be punished in such broad manner fails strict scrutiny when less restrictive means like counterspeech could be employed.
Elected officials typically count as public servants in such state laws. So, in theory, a lobbyist (or any citizen) trying to influence even an elected official (of the kind you enumerated) might fall foul of the "attempt to influence a public servant [by deceit]", if they indeed engage in deceit in such communications. Where is the delineation between that and lying that is protected as political speech, I couldn't tell you. I suspect that the public/prosecutorial interest in pursuing some random person who writes lies to [e.g.] their Senator is pretty low, but it might be (more) justified to e.g. pursue some well greased lobbyist who does the same. But, thus far, I've not been able to turn up any case law like that.
Come to think of it, on a federal level, lobbyists are punished (in real life) under FARA if they lie about receiving foreign funds etc. (I know it's slightly more complicated, they have to be 'controlled' by or 'act on request' of a foreign principal.) But, that's related on the deceit angle, albeit FARA is substantially more specific to a narrow kind of deceit (whom they are lobbying on behalf of, when it's a foreign entity).

Sigh... I was afraid the case and its politics would overshadow my actual question.  Disclosing a password may be interesting for her specific case, but I assume it isn't a way of influencing a public official by means of deceit?

Perhaps all lobbyists follow that ethics code... Or perhaps it's difficult to prove they knowingly misrepresent something.
